# Converting String to Usable Variable

Tags: powershell, xaml

I am working with a larger script that imports XAML so that is why the properties will look different. I have many variables that I need to change the Visibility of based on a button click. So in order to simplify my code I used the following to create an array of variables:

```
[array]$CVariables += Get-Variable lblC* | Select -ExpandProperty Name
$CVariables += Get-Variable txtC* | Select -ExpandProperty Name
$CVariables += Get-Variable btnC* | Select -ExpandProperty Name

[array]$UVariables += Get-Variable lblU* | Select -ExpandProperty Name
$UVariables += Get-Variable txtU* | Select -ExpandProperty Name
$UVariables += Get-Variable btnU* | Select -ExpandProperty Name

[array]$PVariables += Get-Variable lblP* | Select -ExpandProperty Name
$PVariables += Get-Variable txtP* | Select -ExpandProperty Name
$PVariables += Get-Variable btnP* | Select -ExpandProperty Name
```

Seeing that each variable (`$CVariables`, `$UVariables`, and `$PVariables`) will just contain names such as "lblC_Name" and "txtC_Name", I need to convert these into working variables.

I have tried `Get-Variable`, but that just gives me the value.
ex:

```
PS> Get-Variable lblC_Name
#This Yields...
Name: lblC_Name
Value: System.Windows.Controls.Label: Name:
```

My end goal is to get something like this working:

```
if ($lstComputerName.IsSelected) {
    $CVariables | % { $($_).Visibility = "Visible" }
}
```

What I would like to know when looping through an array of strings, how do I convert that to a variable and access properties of that like text/content and visibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a closer look at the output of `Get-Variable lblC_Name` you'll see that the label is in the **`Value`** property of the variable object, so that's what you need to use:

```
$CVariables | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Variable $_ -ValueOnly).Visibility = "Visible"
}
```

or

```
$CVariables | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Variable $_).Value.Visibility = "Visible"
}
```